# From escape velocity to gravitational acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, escape-velocity

If all you are given is the escape velocity from the surface of Earth can you back calculate to Earths 9.8 m/s^2 gravitational acceleration?
In the end what I am looking for is a formula with Escape velocity on one side solving for 9.8 m/s^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, to translate escape velocity $v_{esc}$ at the surface of a planet into gravitational acceleration $g$ at the same location, you also need the radius $R$ of the planet. The equation that applies is: $2 g R = v_{esc}^2$.

Comment: So if you have radius, you can take the escape velocity and divide by $$(2*R) and get g? Excellent that is what i was looking for.

Comment: @Joe - small correction: take **the square of** the escape velocity and divide by twice the radius to get $g$.

Comment: Strictly speaking you also know need to know that the mass distribution is (a) spherically symmetric and (b) confined to smaller radii than your current position. Obviously that is reasonably true *"at the surface of a planet"*, but I thought I'd throw it out there.